# Pulseaudio won't start/work

Tags: pulseaudio

So I just downloaded Pulseaudio, and when I type in the search "pulseaudio" only a picture pops up with a blue M. So I went to try to re-download it. I used the command "sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio" (no "") then "sudo apt-get install pulseaudio" and the same problem occurs. When I try to open it with the terminal "pulseaudio" I get the errors: (I'm typing this) 
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.

Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea I didn't install the correct Pulse-Audio... Basic question right? I installed ProjectM Pulse-audio Visualization  instead of pulse-audio volume control.